# ListView losing content on scroll

Tags: android, listview, android-context

I have a custom list adapter and I wrote this piece of code of getView.
The problem i'm facing is that on scrolling, the content gets mixed up and the images mix with each other.

**getView Method**

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // if view not generated
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.post_list, null);

        holder = new Holder();
        holder.post_text=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.post_text);
        holder.post_platform=(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.post_platform);
        holder.post_image=(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.post_image);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder= (Holder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    String network = getNetworkType(posts_platforms.get(position));

    setHolderData(holder, network, position);
    return convertView;
}
```

**setHolderData Method**

```
private void setHolderData(final Holder holder, String platform, final int position) {
        holder.post_text.setText(posts_texts.get(position));
        holder.post_platform.setImageResource(R.drawable.default_image);
        holder. post_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.default_image);
}
```

Any idea what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Need to see the code to `setHolderData` method.

Comment: I don't understand.  The image resource you are setting is constant R.drawable.default_image. What is getting mixed up?

Comment: Repeated items. Like one item is being shown consecutively four times.

Comment: There is nothing obviously wrong with the code you posted; you will have to show us more code.